# Set textbox value if 2 dropdown selections are true?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please show me why this code isn't working? I'm trying to put text into a textbox if 2 dropdown selections are true.

```js
function test() {
  if (document.getElementById("Accounts").value == "Account1" && document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Company1";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="Accounts">
    <option value="Account1">Account1</option>
    <option value="Account2">Account2</option>
    <option value="Account3">Account3</option>
    <option value="Account4">Account4</option>
    </select>

<select id="DevliveryPlaces">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="Organisation1" />
```

"#Accounts" as well as "#DeliveryPlaces" are dropdowns and "#Organisation1" is a textbox.

Comment: Can we also see your HTML?

Comment: Hi @CarlEdwards it's unfortunately a bit long as it's a big form. However I will find the necessary fields and post them now.

Comment: @gaetanoM I will thank you very much. Will update once I have found a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding `onChange` to each select element. Each time the `onChange` runs it resets the value to empty, and then if the `if` statement applies it changes the value:

```js
function test() {

document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "";

if (document.getElementById("Accounts").value == "Account1" && 
document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value == "1") {
   document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Company1";
}
}
```

```html
<select id="Accounts" onChange="test()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Account1">Account1</option>
<option value="Account2">Account2</option>
</select>

<select id="DeliveryPlaces" onChange="test()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input id="Organisation1" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give the onChange a try!

Answer (score 1):

Compare **all** accounts to **all** places:

```
accountsValue.replace("Account", "") === placesValue
```

If you want to change something in HTML with JavaScript, you have to **add** an **event** with

```
el.addEventListener("event", function() {})
```

**In total** (HTML modified)

```js
var accounts = document.getElementById("accounts"),
  places = document.getElementById("places"),
  organisation = document.getElementById("organisation");

function test() {
  var accountsValue = accounts.value,
    placesValue = places.value;
  if (accountsValue.replace("Account", "") === placesValue) {
    organisation.value = "Organisation" + placesValue;
  } else {
    organisation.value = "";
  }
}

test();

accounts.addEventListener("change", test);
places.addEventListener("change", test);
```

```html
<select id="accounts">
  <option value="Account1">Account1</option>
  <option value="Account2">Account2</option>
  <option value="Account3">Account3</option>
  <option value="Account4">Account4</option>
</select>

<select id="places">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="organisation" />
```

**Hint**

Put the JavaScript at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. Will give this a try too!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your problem is, it is not in your code as it is working:

```js
function test() {
  if (document.getElementById("Accounts").value == "Account1" &&
    document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Company1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Not Company 1";
  }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
<select id="DeliveryPlaces">
<option value="1">DeliveryPlace 1</option>
<option value="2">DeliveryPlace 2</option>
</select>

<select id="Accounts">
<option value="Account1">Account 1</option>
<option value="Account2">Account 2</option>
</select>

<textarea id="Organisation1"></textarea>

<button>test</button>
```

Comment: 'It works' isn't an answer. If it doesn't work for the OP then there must be an underlying issue which your answer does not address. DV isn't me, FYI

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I realise it works, but for some reason on my site it's having an issue. Could be a JS conflict but I'll have to delve deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should get value of selected option and compare

```
  function test() {
        var ddlAccounts = document.getElementById("Accounts");
        var AccountsValue = ddlAccounts.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var ddlDeliveryPlaces = document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces");
        var DeliveryPlacesValue = ddlDeliveryPlaces.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (AccountsValue == "Account1" && DeliveryPlacesValue == "1") {
            document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Company1";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo **select id="DevliveryPlaces"** and you need to call the function. You can do this by adding an event listener as [SWC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9019817/swc) pointed out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="Accounts">
    <option value= "select"></option>
    <option value="Account1">Account1</option>
    <option value="Account2">Account2</option>
    <option value="Account3">Account3</option>
    <option value="Account4">Account4</option>
  </select>

  <select id="DeliveryPlaces">
    <option value= "select"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="Organisation1" />


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      // alert(document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value);
      if (document.getElementById("Accounts").value == "Account1" && document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value == "1") {
        // alert("Working");
        document.getElementById("Organisation1").value = "Company1";
      }
    }
    var deliveryPlaces = document.getElementById('DeliveryPlaces');
    var accounts = document.getElementById('Accounts');
    deliveryPlaces.addEventListener('change', test);
    accounts.addEventListener('change', test);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```